# Android: Checking generated preferences

Tags: android, preferences

I have

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Before the preferences are left I want to do a sanity check. I can do that in activity which calls the preference activity during the `onAcitivtyResult()` method. But that means if I have to tell the user to correct the preferences I have to call the preference activity again which I want to avoid. Is there some way that I can do a check before I leave this preference activity? Something that the user can only leave the preference activity when the sanity check is ok. I guess I have to override the back button, do I?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html to get notified right when a certain preference has been set. From there, you could react accordingly.